# Why am I getting oEvent.getParameter('data') undefined on dataReceived event?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

```js
this.getView().bindElement({
  path: `/Employees('${this._userId}')`,
  parameters: { expand: 'aaa,bbb,ccc' },
  events: {
    dataReceived: (oEvent) => {
      this.getView().setBusy(false)
      debugger
    }
  }
});
```

I can see data in the response of the `$batch` request.
When I put a breakpoint in the `dataReceived` function handler, I can also see the data via `this.getView().getModel().getProperty(this.getView().getBindingContext().getPath())`.
The parameter `oEvent.mParameters.data` exists, but the value is `undefined`.

If I leave out `expand`, the `data` is set. Do all entities of an associated entityset need to have an association to its parent?

Comment: Is the service OData V2 and implemented via SAP Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design according to the API reference of [`dataReceived`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.Binding#events/dataReceived):

> #### dataReceived
>
> [...] This event **may also be fired when an error occurred**.
>
> | Param | type | description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | data | string | The data received; **is `undefined` in error cases** |

You must have somewhere an error message in the $batch response, or the request was somehow aborted.

The missing `data` parameter is currently the only documented indicator for a failed request on `bindObject`/`bindElement`.

---

PS: See also https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2263

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no error in the batch response and no call to `this.getOwnerComponent()          .getModel().attachRequestFailed(function (event) { debugger; })`.

Comment: If I leave out expand, the `data` is set. Do all elements of an associated entityset need to have an association to its parent?

Comment: @Pieter The `$batch` request itself can be successful (status code *20x*) while the contained actual GET request gets rejected by the OData service due to an error (internal status code *40x* or *50x* within the *20x* `$batch` response). Could you check again?

Comment: The response body shows 200 OK for all individual requests.

Comment: Same issue on 1.96.8. I don't have backlinks on the associated entities. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: @Pieter Try the same request URL (with `$expand=aaa,bbb,ccc` and `$format=json`) in the browser's address bar and see if you get the expected results. E.g.: https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders,CustomerDemographics&$format=json

Comment: Yes, the data is looking OK. However, I'm not sure if UI5 requires a 'backlink' to be present on each child entity. In the Northwind example the backlink would be the 'Customer' association on the 'Order' entity.

Comment: It doesn't help that I'm not able to hit a breakpoint in `ODataContextBinding-dbg.js`

Comment: @Pieter I couldn't find any reference in the [OData V2 specification](https://help.sap.com/doc/5890d27be418427993fafa6722cdc03b/Cloud/en-US/OdataV2.pdf) that the *Order* entity type MUST also have a NavigationProperty back to its *Customer*. I'd be surprised if the empty `data` is due to the missing backlink

Comment: @Pieter Did creating a "backlink" resolve the issue?